# how to show database results in a specific column view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i want to show portfolio/work done section on my front view of codeigniter. like a news section that contains a title, image, descriptions and other infos. i am not sure how to do this. please suggest me some reference on how to deal with this.

this is my controller

```
  <?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();       
    }

    public function index()
    {       
     $data['meta_title'] = 'meta title';
     $data['meta_description'] = 'meta desc';
     $data['meta_keywords'] = 'keywords';   
     $data['view'] = 'region/india/home';
     $this->load->model('regions/India_model');
     $data['portfolio'] = $this->India_model->portfolio();
     $this->load->view('region/layout', $data);

    }

}
?>
```

this is my model

```
  <?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class India_model extends CI_Model{

    public function portfolio(){

            $query=$this->db->query("select * from tblportfolio ORDER BY id DESC");
            return $query->result();

        }
}
?>
```

in my view i want all my results in this column type template, for each results it should be in this format. i am not sure how to do this, i have done earlier in tables but in this format, i am not able to get any reference.

variables that is in view is same as column name in database.

kindly suggest how to show all the results from database in view in below format .like every rows data should be in below view format.

this is view part

```
<li class="column">  
<a href="#"">
  <img src="<?php echo $imgsrc;?>" class="w100" />

  <span class="copy border-box pr20 pl20 animate">
      <i class="pointer animate"></i>
         <small class="title orange block pt20 pb10 animate">

              <?php echo $smalltitle;?>

         </small>
  <span class="show-on-desktop"><?php echo $tagline;?></span>
  <span class="show-on-mobile"><?php echo $tagline;?></span>

  <span class="cta">
            <!-- <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-lg"></i> -->
  <span class="icon icon-greyglobal_arrow"></span>                View                </span>
  </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop your html list element for all results in $data['portfolio'] you sent to view.
The code can simply be:

```
<?php foreach($portfolio as $list){ ?> **your html code** <?php } ?>
```

and for showing titles and folio data you can use $list as:

```
<?php echo $list['smalltitle'] ;?>
```

**UPDATE:

Please Follow this syntax.

```
<?php foreach($portfolio as $list){ ?>

    <li class="column">

    <a href="#">
    <div>
      <img src="<?php echo $list->imgsrc; ?>" class="w100" /> 
      <span class="copy border-box pr20 pl20 animate">
          <i class="pointer animate"></i>
             <small class="title orange block pt20 pb10 animate">
                  <?php echo $list->smalltitle;?>
             </small>
      <span class="show-on-desktop"><?php echo $list->tagline; ?></span>
      <span class="show-on-mobile"><?php echo $list->tagline; ?></span>

      <span class="cta">
                <!-- <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-lg"></i> -->
      <span class="icon icon-greyglobal_arrow"></span> View </span>
      </span>
        </span>
     </div>
    </a>
</li>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: No its not working, i have tried with static html code with static data too there, but its not showing, static data is not showing too there.

Comment: @OjibixCreatives Please tell what exact error you having or log of error....are you having problem in your html ? or in php ?

Comment: okay , the issue is , when i use my html code with static data out ( of this <?php foreach($portfolio as $list){ ?> **your html code** <?php } ?> ,) it getting displayed but when i keep html code with static data or with variables data inside this php code in place of **html code** . it just blank, there is no error or any output of that code.

Comment: Please Update your question with full code of your view.php...It looks like you must be having syntactical error...look out for opening closing php tags and html tags...also as you said the code working with database data ie dynamic data...so can you please tell what you actually except with your html code...it'll help me to understand about your problem more clearly....and finally refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29696085/9144250 this...

Comment: i have edited variables , now its working same i have updated in your code sir. thanks for the support.